# Detecting MacOS USB device with libmobiledevice

Tags: libimobiledevice

I have been using this library `https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice` to read and get information from iPhone devices connected via USB
(`https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/blob/bfaf1a132a0d528cfe1dae8cbb4f0ecdeccaa88d/tools/ideviceinfo.c`)

I was wondering if I can use `ideviceinfo.c` to detect another MacOS devices connected via USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, libimobiledevice can connect to iOS devices (as you have done), but macOS devices aren't supported.

You can find more information on their [website](https://libimobiledevice.org/).

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Is there any library that I can use to connect to MacOS devices over USB the same way as libmobiledevice?

Comment: Sorry, I personally do not know of any. I'd bet some Googling could get you some results though.